# What can we say about $\gcd(a,b)$ if $as + bt = 2$ fo rsome $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I have a question I can not figure out (It's #2 in section 4.4 of the book Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics, by Ralph P. Grimaldi).

$\mathbb{Z}^+$ = The set of all positive integers

$\mathbb{Z}$ = The set of all integers

For $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$, what can we say about $\gcd(a,b)$ if:

$as + bt = 2$?

Comment: look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Answer (score 3):

HINT: If $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$, what else in the equation $as+bt=2$ must be divisible by $d$? You might also want to look up [Bézout’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\:d\mid a,b\:\Rightarrow\:d\mid as+bt = 2$

Comment: oh this is better